# Dagger Hilt : cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method. public abstract static class SingletonC implements HybridEntryPoint,

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I have a feature that I am migrating to Hilt. At the present moment after adding
@AndroidEntryPoint for the fragment and @HiltViewModel for the ViewModel.

The classes are below :

**Interface**

```
interface MyInterface {

    fun throwValidation(errorMessage: String, @IdRes viewResId: Int)
}
```

**Fragment**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class OrderReplacementFragment : Fragment(), MyInterface {

    override fun throwValidation(errorMessage: String, viewResId: Int) {
    } 
}
```

**Viewmodel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class OrderReplacementViewModel @Inject constructor(application: Application, private val validation: MyInterface,
  @Named("io") private val ioContext: CoroutineContext) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
   }

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class OrderReplaceCardModule {

    @Module
    abstract class OrderReplaceCardFragmentModule {

        @Binds
        abstract fun bindHandDeliveryDetailsValidationListener(impl: OrderReplacementFragment): MyInterface

    }
}
```

However, when trying to do the build. I get the following error below :

```
/phone/PhoneApp_HiltComponents.java:1064: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.cat.mobile.android.card.interfaces.MyInterface cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements HybridEntryPoint,
                         ^
      com.cat.mobile.android.card.interfaces.MyInterface is injected at
          com.cat.mobile.android.card.orderreplacementcard.viewmodel.OrderReplacementViewModel(…, validation, …)
      com.cat.mobile.android.card.orderreplacementcard.viewmodel.OrderReplacementViewModel is injected at
          com.cat.mobile.android.card.orderreplacementcard.viewmodel.OrderReplacementViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.cat.mobile.phone]
```

How best can I go in resolving this issue ?

Comment: You showed us an interface called `MyInterface`, but where is it being used? Then you implement an interface called `SomeValidation` in a `Fragment` class and uses the same `SomeValidation` interface as a parameter for dependency injection of a `ViewModel` class, this is really what you want? And finally, the `Hilt` module you have will not make sense because you are saying that the implementation of `SomeValidation` must be a `Fragment` class that are a `AndroidEntryPoint`, the right way is to assign a specific implementation class for the logic in question.

Comment: You can also check the Hilt docs to understand how the [Binds Module](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android?hl=en#inject-interfaces) and [Provides Module](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android?hl=en#inject-provides) should be.

Comment: @ThalesIsidoro i have updated my question. Sorry had forgotten to update the interface names